# 'Input not supported' error and no Grub after upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04

Tags: upgrade, grub2

Running Windows Vista and Ubuntu 11.04 on an Acer tower.  Was running 10.10 with kernel `2.6.35.32`, running great.  Upgraded to 11.04 from Update Manager, re-boot results in `Input Not Supported` error, then a short delay, then 11.04 boots, but without GRUB menu.  I would like to get to version 12.04, but am afraid to continue until I get 11.04 running error-less.

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall your grub with this tutorial:
http://odzangba.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/455/

greetings